# Monodevelop on Mac: `Mono.framework MDK is missing`

Tags: macos, monodevelop, monomac, dmg

In Monodevelop, if I enable the `Include the Mono runtime in the application bundle` checkbox, then I get this error at build:

```
Merging Mono Runtime into app bundle
/Applications/MonoDevelop.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/monodevelop/AddIns/MonoDevelop.MonoMac/mmp -nolink "-minos=10.6" -o "/Users/Kizumi/src/CmisSync/SparkleShare/Mac/bin/Debug" -n "SparkleShare" -a "/Users/Kizumi/src/CmisSync/bin/SparkleLib.dll" -a "/Users/Kizumi/src/CmisSync/bin/SparkleLib.Cmis.dll" -a "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.9/lib/mono/4.0/System.dll" -a "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.9/lib/mono/4.0/System.Xml.dll" -a "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.9/lib/mono/4.0/System.Core.dll" -a "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.9/lib/mono/4.0/System.Drawing.dll" -a "/Applications/MonoDevelop.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/monodevelop/AddIns/MonoDevelop.MonoMac/MonoMac.dll" -a "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.9/lib/mono/4.0/System.Net.dll" -a "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.9/lib/mono/4.0/Mono.Posix.dll" "/Users/Kizumi/src/CmisSync/SparkleShare/Mac/bin/Debug/SparkleShare.exe"
Mono.framework MDK is missing. Please install the MDK for your Mono.framework version from http://mono-project.com/Downloads
mmp exited with code 252
```

I comply with all requirements at http://www.mono-project.com/MonoMacPackager :

- On Snow Leopard I installed XCode 3.2.6 (last XCode version that runs on Snow Leopard), the minimum requirement being XCode 3.2.5
- `Application Tools` seems to be included in XCode since 3.2.6 so I don't need to install another package.
- I installed Mono 2.10.9
- I installed Monodevelop 3.0.5
- I have MonoMac 3.0.5 enabled in Monodevelop

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that despite having Monodevelop I only had the `Mono MRE`.

As suggested bt the error message, the solution was to install the `Mono MDK`, which can be found alongside the MRE here: http://www.go-mono.com/mono-downloads/download.html

Comment: The download links for MDK and MRE are right next to each other without explanation, so I can see how you'd do that.